# php, sql individual links for Group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three table, movies, artist, and role_table. The role_table holds only movieCode from movies and artistID from artist which are the primary keys of movies and artist table. i used join to get the values and Group_concat. here is my sql code

```
SELECT m.Title, m.MovieDesc, m.image, m.catagory, a.ID, a.FullName,
GROUP_CONCAT(a.FullName )
FROM movies m
JOIN role_table r ON m.movieCode =r.movieCode_FK
JOIN artist a ON r.artistID_FK = a.ID
where
movieCode = '$movieCode
```

This code is perfect fine and it works. what i want is to get the individual links for those artist which gets the values from The group_concat. 
i am stuck here and any kind of help will be great.
Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by individual links?

Comment: for example if i have 3 artist which are related to LOTR movies, let say, tom, will and benedict. this group_concat will give a output like this, LOTR and these artist on the same row or line Tom, will , benedict. what i want is; to make url of each name separately or if i say directly, i want their own outputs links for example like this <a href like this kind of. i tried to make link and those all three artist has the same one link. i want three separate link php code :) i hope you understand :)

Comment: Best off done in your application. While you could use GROUP_CONCAT on links built up using CONCAT and this would work most of the time, the problem will be when the name contains html characters that will wreck the link.

Comment: could you please tell me how to make a link for it. if i try to use normal link inside the echo, then it makes  one link for all tom, will and benedict and it takes the id only of tom. please tell me, How do i echo, so that it takes all those three ids separately and make a separate links for each? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it in php (assiming you are using a database class):-

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT m.Title, m.MovieDesc, m.image, m.catagory, a.ID, a.FullName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(a.FullName ) AS ConcatFullName
        FROM movies m
        JOIN role_table r ON m.movieCode =r.movieCode_FK
        JOIN artist a ON r.artistID_FK = a.ID
        where movieCode = '$movieCode'";

$db->query($sql) or die($db->error());

while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $fullnames = explode(',', $row['ConcatFullName']);
    foreach($fullnames AS $aFullName)
    {
        echo "<a href='SomeLink.php?".urlencode($aFullName).">".htmlspecialchars($aFullName)."</a>";
    }
}

?>
```